# Concentrations of Adult Math Phobia

Tags: arithmetic, remedial-courses

Some professions have more math phobia than others. Few engineers hate math, but many [teachers](https://www.thestar.com/yourtoronto/education/2016/05/13/for-many-teachers-math-just-doesnt-add-up.html) and [journalists](http://www.niemanlab.org/2013/11/matt-waite-how-i-faced-my-fears-and-learned-to-be-good-at-math/) do. This means that university departments of education and journalism would likely have a high concentration of adults in need of people like, well, us. :)

Does anybody know of other niches where lots of adults require help with math?

---

Edit: The link about journalism is a source to back up the proposition that many journalists do not like or excel at math. I *totally* disagree with his notion that simply trying harder will work for all people and all students. Often the problem is prior knowledge and/or non-academic issues. The author could experience this first-hand by jumping into a 4th-year level math course and seeing what difference trying really hard makes.

Comment: Nice links, thanks for those.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm looking for more just like them. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hatred is not equal to phobia (fear). Not meant to nit, but being precise helps in the issue analysis.

I suspect that those who are better at math, like it more (hate it less) and fear it less.  [OK, point one has some sub correlation! ;-)]

Different jobs require different amounts of math, regardless of whether the people fear/hate math.  An engineer needs a certain math skill (at least for his classes...in the field much less, but even then some in the field.)  Journalists do not.  You may say they would benefit from it, but so what...we could all benefit from learning Greek...but it's not a PRIORITY.  It's a lot more important that journalists have writing skills.

---

But to actually answer your question!

The one practical thing I would say for you is that many MBA students (and even some McKinsey consultants!) come back to learning basic finance and econ at age 30 or so and are intimidated by math.  It's a subset.  The engineers and scientists think the stuff is a breeze and wish it were more mathy.  But the English majors and such are intimidated by it.

I know that some MBA schools have little summer prep programs for the weaker math students to help them out (even very prestigious schools).  And McKinsey's "mini MBA" (crash MBA for non MBA Ph.D.s) has a prep week of math for those with weak math backgrounds.  I would also add that these are relatively high paying environments and students are relatively well behaved.

Here is a textbook for this sort of work:

[https://www.amazon.com/Basic-Mathematics-Economists-Mike-Rosser/dp/0415267846/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1518032580&sr=1-2#customerReviews](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415267846)

(for amusement see the "too easy" complaint of the "buckle up and read your Rudin" math snob.)